# Matlab: plots to subplot

Tags: matlab, figure

I want to reproduce plots from figures to subplot of new figure. Consider the following

```
f1 = figure;
p1 = plot([1 2],[1 2], 'r');
legend(p1, 'Test')

f2 = figure;
p2 = plot([2 3], [2 3], 'g');

f3 = figure;

h1 = subplot(1,2,1);
h2 = subplot(1,2,2);
```

Now, my purpose is to reproduce `p1` and `p2` as subplots of `f3`. I have tried many combinations including following and it did not worked

```
ax1 = copyobj(f1.Children, h1);
ax2 = copyobj(f2.Children, h2);
```

Answer to similar question at [this link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/366033-already-saved-subplots-to-subplots-including-title-and-labels) did not helped. I am using R2016b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
f1 = figure;
p1 = plot([1 2],[1 2], 'r');
legend(p1, 'Test')

f2 = figure;
p2 = plot([2 3], [2 3], 'g');

f3 = figure;

h1 = subplot(1,2,1);
h2 = subplot(1,2,2);

ax1 = copyobj(p1, h1);
ax2 = copyobj(p2, h2);
```

Figure three displays the two subplots with data from p1 and p2 as required:

[image]